# Trouble catching exception

Tags: php, exception

I'm working on a simple MVC framework and I am using autoloading of classes and I want to use `class_eixists()` to check if the controller name parsed from the URI actually exists and respond appropriately.  I started with

```
$controller = "\\namespace\\controller";
if(class_exists($controller))
   $this->controllerObject = new $controller();
else
    // react appropriately
```

This ended up throwing an uncaught logic exception if the class didn't exists.  If my google-fu hasn't failed me then this is a normal event when using autoloading and the `class_exists()` function.  I figured no big deal and wrapped it in a try catch but I'm still getting the uncaught exception and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
try {
     if (class_exists($controller))  {
        $this->controllerObject = new $controller(array_slice($parsedURI, 1));
        echo "controller is $controller<br />";
     }   
  } catch (LogicException $e) {
     $e->getMessage();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     $e->getMessage();
  }
```

The error output is below.  Line 57 is the line with (`if (class_exists($controller))`). I changed up the actual paths manually because the system administrator is paranoid about any internal info being made public.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Class 
Controller\Gibberish could not be loaded' in     some/path/private/webroot/assets/route.php:57 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: 
spl_autoload('Controller\Gibb...') #1 
some/path/private/app/webroot/assets/route.php(57): class_exists('\Controller\Gib...') 
#2 some/path/private/app/webroot/index.php(32): Assets\Route-
>__construct('/add/webroot/...') #3 {main} thrown in 
some/path/private/app/webroot/assets/route.php on line 57
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Nothing is throwing an *exception* here. Sure you don't simply get *Fatal Errors*?

Comment: class_exists will throw an exception

Comment: I know it throws the exception, the problem is my try/catch not catching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost 2 hours of searching for an answer before I post and less than half of one afterward before I find the answer.  The reason I couldn't catch the exception is because the logic is inside a method of a class that is inside a namespace.  In order to catch the `LogicException` it has to be prefixed with a `\` to specify the global namespace.

```
try {
   if (class_exists($controller))  {
      $this->controllerObject = new $controller(array_slice($parsedURI, 1));
      echo "controller is $controller<br />";
   }   
} catch (\LogicException $e) {
   $e->getMessage();
}
```

I found two other questions with an identical issue:

[PhpMailer throwing Fatal Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147684/phpmailer-throwing-fatal-exceptions)

[Facebook PHP SDK Throwing an Uncatchable OAuthException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402939/facebook-php-sdk-throwing-an-uncatchable-oauthexception)